# Conditions a discontinuous f must obey so $\int f$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

What conditions must a discontinuous $f$ satisfy for the $\int\limits_{-\infty}^x f(u) \ dP$ to be continuous?
I would say the set of discontinuities must have measure zero. Is it also sufficient?
Am I missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\int f(x)dP$ is at first sight not a function but a number so talking about continuity makes no sense. Or do you mean something like $g(x)=\int f(x,\omega)P(d\omega)$?

Comment: @drhab thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the question.

Comment: At first sight I think it is enough that $f$ takes value $0$ on the set $\{u\mid P(\{u\})>0\}$. Every $u$ with $P(\{u\})>0$ and $f(u)\neq0$ is a discontinuity point. Btw, you must be careful with notation $\int_{-\infty}^x$. If you write $\int_{(-\infty,x]}f(u)dP$ or $\int1_{(-\infty,x]}(u)f(u)dP$ instead then it is more clear that point $x$ is "in" the integration, which is quite important here.

Comment: @drhab For example, let f(x)=e^-x, x>0, and f(x)=0, x<0. We have a discontinuity at x=0, but $\int_{(-\infty,x]}f(u) du$ is continuous everywhere.

Comment: First, for the integral to make sense, $f$ has to be measurable and integrable over each set $(-\infty,a)$, $a\in\mathbb R$. Given that, $\int_{-\infty}^xf\,dt$ is continuous.

Comment: That's correct. In the same line: a function $f$ can serve as PDF of a distribution if it is measurable, non-negative and satisfies $\int f(u)du=1$. That is enough (in fact even a bit more than enough). It is allowed to be discontinuous as wild as it wants. Nevertheless the corresponding CDF will always be continuous. Here we are dealing with $P=$ the Lebesguemeasure so that the set $\{u\mid P(\{u\})>0\}$ mentioned in my former comment is empty.

Comment: Oh, no, wait. $dP$ is not the Lebesgue measure. So, it depends on how the measure $dP$ behaves at the discontinuities.

Comment: For an example with many discontinuities, let $f(x) = 1/(1 + x^2)$ if $x$ is irrational, and $f(x) = 0$ if $x$ is rational. Then $f$ is discontinuous everywhere, but $\int_{-\infty}^x f$ should be continuous.

Comment: @Joppy I said this already above. If $dP$ is Lebesgue measure, then the integral function is continuous, whenever $f$ is only assumed to be integrable. The problem here is that $dP$ is _not_ necessarily Lebesgue measure.

Comment: @amsmath Ok, let's assume that we're dealing with the lebesgue measure. When f is integrable in those sets,  will it make the integral continuous or just right-continuous? Asking for

Comment: @amsmath But I still would like to know the case when P is not lebesgue. :)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f$ be integrable over each set $(-\infty,a)$, $a\in\mathbb R$. Then, if $x > x_0$,
$$
\int_{(-\infty,x]}f\,dP - \int_{(-\infty,x_0]}f\,dP = \int_{(x_0,x]}f\,dP = \int_{(-\infty,x_0+1)}\chi_{(x_0,x]}f\,dP.
$$
The integral on the RHS tends to zero as $x$ approaches $x_0$ by Lebesgue's theorem. Hence, the function is always right-continuous. If $x < x_0$, then
$$
\int_{(-\infty,x_0]}f\,dP - \int_{(-\infty,x]}f\,dP = \int_{(x,x_0]}f\,dP = f(x_0)P(\{x_0\}) + \int_{(-\infty,x_0+1)}\chi_{(x,x_0)}f\,dP.
$$
Hence, the limit as $x\to x_0$ is zero if and only if either $f(x_0) = 0$ or if $P$ does not have mass at $x_0$.

Here, $(x_0,x]$ means either $(x_0,x]$ when $x > x_0$ or $[x,x_0)$, when $x < x_0$.

The discontinuities of $f$ are not important here. For example, let $f=1$ and let $P$ be the probability measure that has mass one at zero. Then
$$
\int_{(-\infty,x]}f\,dP = \begin{cases}0 &\text{if }x < 0\\1 &\text{if }x\ge 0\end{cases}.
$$
So, there is a jump at zero although $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So, it seems that the set of discontinuities must have measure zero (if $f \neq 0$), or may be bigger (even in an uncountable set) but then we must have $f=0$ for all.

Comment: As far as I can see from the above, the discontinuities of $f$ do not matter at all. The discontinuities of the integral function are at those points at which $P$ has mass and $f$ does not vanish. Even if $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Many thanks! ;)

Comment: I edited the answer by adding an example.

Comment: I saw it, thanks. It's helpful ;)